# Parsing JSON URL from API into readable text in Unity/C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, networking, jsonparser

I'm trying to format JSON data from an API and store the results.

The data consists of the local weather and provides accurate temperatures based on the current time.

Below is the C# script of what I've tried so far:

**jsonDataController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class jsonDataController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string jsonURL = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=0ee485dfa1af4123a1a103953221107&q=London&aqi=no";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(generateData());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    IEnumerator generateData()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(jsonURL);
        yield return www;
        if(www.error == null)
        {
            processJsonData(www.text)
        }
    }

    protected void processJsonData(string url)
    {
        jsonDataClass jsonData = JsonUtility.FromJson<jsonDataClass>(url);
        Debug.Log(jsonData.local);
        Debug.Log(jsonData.current);
    }
}
```

**jsonDataClass.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class jsonDataClass
{
    public string location; 
    public List<locationClass> local;
    public List<currentClass> current;

}

[Serializable]
public class locationClass
{
    public string name;
    public string region;
    public string country;
    public float lat;
    public float lon;
    public string tz_id;
    public int localtime_e;
    public string localtime;

}

[Serializable]
public class currentClass
{
    public float temp_c;
    public float temp_f;
    public string last_updated;

}
```

And this is my JSON data:

```
{
  "location": {
    "name": "London",
    "region": "City of London, Greater London",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "lat": 51.52,
    "lon": -0.11,
    "tz_id": "Europe/London",
    "localtime_epoch": 1657576622,
    "localtime": "2022-07-11 22:57"
  },
  "current": {
    "last_updated_epoch": 1657575900,
    "last_updated": "2022-07-11 22:45",
    "temp_c": 24,
    "temp_f": 75.2,
    "is_day": 0,
    "condition": {
      "text": "Clear",
      "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png",
      "code": 1000
    },
    "wind_mph": 5.6,
    "wind_kph": 9,
    "wind_degree": 220,
    "wind_dir": "SW",
    "pressure_mb": 1023,
    "pressure_in": 30.21,
    "precip_mm": 0,
    "precip_in": 0,
    "humidity": 44,
    "cloud": 0,
    "feelslike_c": 24.8,
    "feelslike_f": 76.6,
    "vis_km": 10,
    "vis_miles": 6,
    "uv": 6,
    "gust_mph": 6,
    "gust_kph": 9.7
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix classes

```
[Serializable]
public class jsonDataClass
{
    public locationClass location;
    public currentClass current;
}


[Serializable]
public class conditionClass
    {
        public string text ;
        public string icon ;
        public int code ;
    }

[Serializable]
public class currentClass
{
    public float temp_c;
    public float temp_f;
    public string last_updated;
   public conditionClass condition;
}
 // add all another fields starting from "wind_mph" to currentClass too
```

Comment: It is not necessary to have all the JSON fields. If they are non-existent those JSON fields will simply be ignored/lost. @PepwaveDave what Serge is telling you here: Your `c#` data structure doesn't match the JSON structure. Simply paste your JSON into https://json2csharp.com and it will spit out the correct data structure ... Serge just omitted half of it for whatever reason ;)